# Why does "if-else" work differently from the ternary operator "?:" in this case?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-operator

Declaring classes

```
class A
{
    public string a;
    public static implicit operator A(B b) => new A() { a = b.b };
}
class B
{
    public string b;
}
```

comparison `?:` and `if-else`

```
static public A Method1(B b)
{ 
    return (b is null) ? null : b; //equally return b;
}
static public A Method2(B b)
{
    if (b is null) return null; else return b;
}
```

Method1 will throw an exception
Method2 will work fine

```
Method1(null);
Method2(null);
```

Why do they behave differently?

Comment: Q: are "if/else" and the ternary operator "equivalent"?  Sure, for the most part.  Q: Was Anders Hejlsberg original decision to exclude operator overloading from C# a wise choice?  Yes, definitely :)

Comment: What about these two snippets don't you understand?  Why do you think the first snippet shouldn't call the implicit operator when the value is null, or why do you think the second should?

Comment: There's a lot going on here, but... You don't need the IL to know that an `if` statement is a statement and the ternary operator is an expression.  So no, not equivalent.  The primary reason `?:` exists is to do ["inline if's;"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) they are a convenient shorthand that can be used in things like print statements.

Comment: @Богдан Technically it *is* possible to turn any arbitrary `if/else` into a use of a conditional operator (or the reverse).  It's not always a good idea, but it's technically *possible*.  Obviously in this case you did not do the conversion in a way that maintained the same semantics.  You could have though.

Comment: Neither processors nor MSIL know anything about the conditional operator.  So it needs to be translated to code that they *do* understand.  Which is the same logic the if-statement uses.  Translating from a rich syntax to crippled, but fast, executable code is the basic job of a language compiler.

Comment: I have no idea how this was closed as opinion-based. There's absolutely nothing that is remotely subjective about it! I've edited the question to clarify it more and voted to reopen, @14832315. Feel free to edit it further if you think I messed something up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a ternary operator in `Method1`, the type of the return value must be the same in both branches (`B`, in your case). That value has to be cast to `A` later to match the return type of the method. So, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown in your implicit operator (because `b` is null).

In `Method2`, on the other hand, you're returning `null` *directly*; so, no cast is needed.

You get the same result (i.e., exception) in `Method2` if you change it into something like this:

```
static public A Method2(B b)
{
    B temp;
    if (b is null) temp = null; else temp = b;
    return temp; // Throws a NullReferenceException.
}
```

What you ought to be doing is adding a null-check in the implicit operator:

```
public static implicit operator A(B b) => (b is null ? null : new A { a = b.b });
```

Comment: @Богдан Because the ternary operator must have a _unified_ return type. If one branch is retunring `B`, the other one must return `B` as well. Consider this `var test = someBool ? null : new Person();` and then ask yourself "what's the type of `test`?".

Comment: @Богдан There's no "or"; it must have a specific type. Let me quote from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator): _"If a target type of a conditional expression is unknown (for example, when you use the var keyword) or in C# 8.0 and earlier, the type of consequent and alternative must be the same or there must be an implicit conversion from one type to the other"_

Answer (score 0):

`Method1`

For the ternary operator type of return values should be equal.
So `null` is actually returned as `(B)null`, which then uses implicit operator to get converted to type `A`

`Method2`

The return value is directly converted to `(A)null`, and implicit operator is not used.

`Bonus`

Try changing return type of `Method1` to `B` and it should work.

```
    public static B Method1(B b)
    {
        return (b is null) ? null : b;                  
    }
```